# copy items in XML into for loop

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have servel items such as buttons and scrollview , tablelayout .. etc in my XML file
with custom height and width and Y , X .

I want to copy this item's in for loop to make this items created in each for loop stage automatically with out editing xml again .

it should convert this XML items to programming code first ? and how ?

code XML:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="394dp"
    android:layout_height="389dp"
    android:layout_x="-12dp"
    android:layout_y="106dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back1" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/CheckBox18"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:button="@drawable/test"  />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView34"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                android:text="hesham abdulhamid elnemr" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView35"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="095110263" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What does "copy in a for-loop" mean *exactly*?

Comment: i have table layout ok ? i want to make for loop and create a "copy" for that table-layout in the same pos and coordinates etc , so i want to copy

Comment: Let's try a different approach: What do you want to *archive* by copying the layout?